# Using Express in firebase calls function but creates a timeout

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm a bit at loss here.

I have the following node.js setup:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var https = require('https');

admin.initializeApp();

let app = express();

app.use(cookieParser);


// Set/Get Cookie

app.get('/setuser', (req, res) => {
    console.log('**************SET USER');
    console.log('**************req:');
    console.log(req);

    console.log('**************res:');
    console.log(res);
    res.send('setting user');
});

app.get('/getuser', (req, res) => {

    console.log('**************GET USER');
    console.log('**************req:');
    console.log(req);

    console.log('**************res:');
    console.log(res);
    res.send('getting user');
    //res.send(req.cookies);
});

exports.main = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

In the firebase.json file I have:

```
"hosting": {
    "site": "sso-login",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/main/**",
        "function": "main"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm running the whole app in locally in the firebase simulator.

Now, when I call

```
https://localhost:5100/main/getuser Or https://localhost:5100/main/getuser/
```

The simulator's console says `Beginning execution of "main"` - and then nothing happens.

If I remove the rewrites from the firebase.json, I get a simple 404-error.

How do I make my setuser/getuser-functions work?

Comment: Did you tried remove the rewrite and do request to https://localhost:5100/getuser ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Then I get just a 404

Comment: If the emulator doesn't seem to be working for a very clear and simple use case, you could post an issue on the project GitHub.  Be sure your Firebase CLI is up to date, and include full instructions on how to duplicate.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must send a response in firebase HTTP functions.
the simulator stuck probably because of comment on the response lines.
you can read about in the docs 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: Well, I tried this, too. -> res.send('response'); - still the simulator times out.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue at all.  There is clearly a line of code to send a response in both routes.

Comment: @DougStevenson - I edited my question. That line was commented out before. But uncommenting it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. I don't know if it will help you also, but like you are using cookie-parser, I was using the bodyParser package. Removing this one line of code solved my timeout issues.

Comment: This extended the timeout duration. 

I am still facing the timeout error, but after some more seconds.